# How do I add spaces in my program accordingly?

Tags: python, python-3.x

What I mean, I want to make a program that prints stars according to the user input
and I did it:

```
for i in range(num):
  print((i*-1)*' ' + (i+1)*'*')



for o in range(num-1):  
  print((num-o-1)*'*')
```

except instead of this:

```
 *
* *
 *
```

I get this:

```
*
**
*
```

How do I implement the spaces? Thank in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you multiply a string by a negative number, you just get the empty string. And your formulas aren't correct to begin with. You need to pad the front with enough spaces to make it line up (in a monospaced terminal).

Here's one way to do it correctly

```
>>> def diamond(n):
...     print(' '*n + '*')
...     for i in list(range(1,n)) + list(range(n,0,-1)):
...             print('{}*{}*'.format(' '*(n-i), ' '*(2*i-1)))
...     print(' '*n + '*')
```

Converting the ranges to lists isn't efficient for large n, but it's not a bottleneck and the terminal only practically supports widths up to 80 characters anyway.

Comment: If you want the middle to be filled with asterisks, just change the middle print line to something like `' '*(n-i) + '*'*(2*i+1))`

Comment: sorry, when I put 2 it gave the result which is supposed to be given for 3

Comment: I'm not sure how you want it scaled. But you can just divide the argument by two or subtract or whatever to get it scaled how you want.